# POSTGRESQL = show data between time with distinct and in

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have table its about attendance

i want to show the data just in this range ('2017-11-11 03:00:00 **TO** 2017-11-11 08:00:00') where range in 2017-11-11 03:00:00 and 2017-11-11 23:00:00

its my postgres sql

```
select DISTINCT on (a.userid) a.userid, b.name, a.checktime
FROM checkinout a LEFT JOIN
     userinfo b
     on a.userid = b.userid
where a.checktime >= '2017-12-05 03:00:00' AND
      a.checktime <= '2017-12-05 08:00:00' IN (SELECT checktime FROM checkinout where checktime >='2017-12-05 03:00:00' AND checktime <='2017-12-05 23:00:00')
```

the error is operator does not exist: boolean = timestamp without time zone

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you intend:

```
select distinct on (ci.userid) ci.userid, ui.name, ci.checktime
from checkinout ci left join
     userinfo ui
     on ui.userid = ci.userid
where ci.checktime >= '2017-12-05 03:00:00' and
      ci.checktime <= '2017-12-05 08:00:00' and
      ci.check_time in (select checktime
                        from checkinout 
                        where checktime >= '2017-12-05 03:00:00' AND checktime <='2017-12-05 23:00:00'
                       );
```